# bash execute whole script but return exit code > 0 if any intermediate job has failed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script `script.sh` made like:

```
./step1.sh
./step2.sh
./step3.sh
```

Each of the step*.h scripts returns proper error codes whether they failed or not.

Now if step3.sh fails I get an appropriate exit code, but if either step1.sh or step2.sh fails and step3.sh succeeds than I get status = 0, which is not ideal.

I know I can use

```
set -e
```

at the top of my script to make the script fail if any of the intermediate steps fail, but that is not what I want.

I would like to know if there is an easy option to use to execute each of the intermediate scripts (even if one of them fails) but return an exit code > 0 if any of them fails without having to keep track of each individual exit code manually.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `set -e`, what is the expected behaviour you want? Should `step3.sh` continue to run if step2.sh` failed?

Comment: How about as each intermediate steps fail,set different bit of a integer

Comment: @ffledgling yes each intermediate step should keep running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trap errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "test start."

trap 'rc=$?' ERR

./error.sh
./script2.sh

echo "test done."
return ${rc}
```

For more information on how traps work, see [trap](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/trap).

Answer (score 1):

Boiling down to the absolute basics,

```
rc=0
./step1 || rc=$?
./step2 || rc=$?
./step3 || rc=$?
exit $rc
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to "keep track of each individual exit code manually" apparently.

Comment: I left off the `.sh` extension because it's usually a bad idea to have one. According to your tags, these are Bash scripts, not `sh` scripts; and, hard-coding an extension means you can't replace the command with a reimplementation in another language (and still keep the same file name, with honesty preserved).

Comment: @dood We don't keep track, we overwrite in the case of an error.  But yeah, I upvoted your answer already (-:

Comment: I agree with @dood :) I don't want to manually add condition every time..

Comment: @lucacerone Please take a look at my answer then.

Comment: @dood yes this is the one I like the most so far :) just waiting to check if there is any other answers. I'd like to thank all people who took the time to give me a solution though I really appreciated and learnt a few new tricks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# array with all the scripts to be executed
arr=(./step1.sh ./step2.sh ./step3.sh)

# initialize return status to 0
ret=0

# run a loop to execute each script
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do

   echo "running $i"
   bash "$i"
   ret=$((ret | $?)) # return status from previous step bitwise OR with current status

done

echo "exiting with status: $ret"

exit $ret
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially keeping keeping track of each exit code manually, i.e exactly what OP said he didn't want to do?

Comment: I believe OP wants to execute all steps irrespective of exit status of each step but still want to exit with failure if any step fails.

Comment: @anubhava that's exactly what I want I want to do. But I wanted to know if there is any option that would allow to skip the checks manually. Anyway I like your solution!

Comment: I modified it further to make it tidy and to avoid repetitive code.

Comment: thanks.. though it is still not what my question asks :D

Answer (score 0):

I know you stated you didn't want to have to maintain every exit code but that's actually pretty easy to do with arrays:

```
declare -a rcs
./step1.sh ; rcs+=($?)
./step2.sh ; rcs+=($?)
./step3.sh ; rcs+=($?)
```

Then you can simply step through the array in a loop, looking for the first (or largest, last, average, sum, etc) error code to do with as you wish. The code below shows how to do this to return the *first* error encountered:

```
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#rcs[@]}; idx++)); do
    [[ ${rcs[$idx]} -ne 0 ]] && return ${rcs[$idx]}
done
return 0
```

Similarly, to get the *largest* error:

```
rc=0
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#rcs[@]}; idx++)); do
    [[ ${rcs[$idx]} -gt $rc ]] && rc=${rcs[$idx]}
done
return $rc
```

Comment: Are you submitting this for a code obfuscation contest?

Comment: @dood: nice one. Unfortunately, most people use only the smallest parts of `bash`, not realising its true power. It should hopefully be understandable by anyone with a smattering of C knowledge. If not, it's a darn good learning opportunity :-)